# C++ отсутствует оператор, соответствующий этим операндам <<

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct STUDENT
{
  char name[10];
  char surname[10];
  char patronymic[10];
  int numbergroup[10];
  float points[10];
};

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
  const int n = 5;
  STUDENT aray[n] = {};
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cout << '\nИмя\t';
    cin.getline(aray[i].name,3);

    cout << "\n Фамилия\t";
    cin >> aray[i].surname;

    cout << "\n Отчество\t";
    cin >> aray[i].patronymic;

    cout << "\n Номер группы\t";
    cin >> aray[i].numbergroup;

    cout << "\n Средний балл\t";
    cin >> aray[i].points;
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, отсутствует... Кстати, студент у вас может учиться в десяти группах одновременно?.. И, вероятно, в каждой иметь свой средний балл? И, кстати еще раз, вы максимальный размер имени выбрали исходя из своего *Desperate*?

Comment: вообще я хотел задать 2 массива для 2 студентов, но он начал ругаться, что ему мало и я увеличил колличество.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо ограничиться одним числом:

```
struct STUDENT
{
  char name[10];
  char surname[10];
  char patronymic[10];
  int numbergroup;
  float points;
};
```

Или, если надо массив, скажем,

```
  float points[10];
```

то соответственно надо и читать его поэлементно, скажем,

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)  cin >> aray[i].points[j];
```